# Search method that finds an element by cutting an array in halves (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search

I'm working on an assignment.
What I must create is a method that searches for an specific int in an array. It is assumed that the array is already sorted from lowest to highest number. But the condition is that it must search by cutting said array by half and checking in which of the halves the target number is in, then cut said half in half again and so on so on.

We were asked not to use recursive methods as well.

This is the code I came up with but I fail to see my mistake, any help to understand the problem better is more than appreciated!!!

```
public static boolean SearchInHalf(int[] array, int targetint)
{

    int fin = array[array.length-1]; 
    int init = array[0];
    int range = fin-init;

    if ( targetint>array[array.length-1] || targetint< array[0])
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (range>=2)
    {
        int half = array[range/2];

        if (targetint>half)
        {
            init = half;
            range = fin-init;
            half = array[range/2];
        }
        else if (targetint<half)
        {
            fin = half;
            range = fin-init;
            half = array[range/2];
        }
        else if (targetint==half || targetint==fin || targetint==init)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: For one thing your range variable contains the range of values that are actually contained within the array. You should not be using that to dereference your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is known as the "Binary Search". For binary search to work, the elements in the array must already be ordered (which is your case, let's assume ascending). The binary search first compares the key with the element in the middle of the array:

- If the key is less than the middle element, you need to continue to search for the key only in the first half of the array.
- If the key is greater than the middle element, you need to continue to search for the key only in the second half of the array.
- If the key is equal to the middle element, the search ends with a match.

So binary search method eliminates at least half of the array after each comparison. Assuming you will call this method in your static main function:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
  int low = 0;
  int high = list.length - 1;

  while(high >= low) { //search array until there is a single element left
    int mid = (low + high) / 2; //mark middle index
    if (key < list[mid]) //if key is smaller than the middle element..
      high = mid - 1;  //new high is the middle element
    else if (key == list[mid]) //if key=middle element --> voila!
      return mid; //returns the index of searched element if it is in your array
    else
      low = mid + 1; //if key is greater than the middle element new low is middle element
  }
  return –low - 1;  //high < low, key not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (targetint>array[array.length-1] || targetint<array[0])
        return false;

    int middleInt = array[Math.round(array.length/2)];
    if (middleInt == targetint) {
        return true;
    } else if (targetint<middleInt) {
        int[] firstHalf = new int[array.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, firstHalf, 0, firstHalf.length);
        array = firstHalf;
    } else if (targetint>middleInt) {
        int[] secondHalf = new int[array.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(array, array.length/2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalf.length);
        array = secondHalf;
    } else if(array.length == 1)
        return false;
}
```